# Displaying a synchronized countdown timer with server side automatic time logout?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, timer

I'm following [this example](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2008/12/12/automatic-session-timeout-logout-using-php-and-ajax-part-ii/) of a PHP session timer using an AJAX call to check the 'time'.

I would like to be able to display some kind of display for the user that is simply a javascript countdown timer such as:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var length = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(length, display);
};
```

but with `var length` equal to the value specified at `$_SESSION['timeOut'] = SomeNumber;` in the php file.

How can I set these to be exactly in sync and be able to output the countdown to the screen? Or am I able to just utilize the php timing and not necessarily create a js timer?

Comment: If you want to see a countdown on the page itself, then you have to use JavaScript; PHP can’t achieve that (unless you would constantly reload the page, which would be rather nonsense). A timeout value of exactly 1000 miliseconds however will not be that reliable, especially over longer periods of time – you’ll be better of with using JavaScript `Date` objects to get the actual current client time, and calculate the difference from that.

Answer (score 0):

you can get time of now measured by seconds using php function `time()` and then save it as time of login in your DB .every time user refresh the page.you must send him `$_SESSION['timeOut'] + ($time_of_login) - time()` wich returns how much seconds to reach time out

`$time_of_login` from DB

so php file will look like:

```
var length = <? echo $_SESSION['timeOut'] + ($time_of_login) - time(); ?>
```